# Another triple integral

Tags: real-analysis, multiple-integral

I have $$D=\{(x,y,z): x^2<z^2<x^2+y^2\wedge x>0\wedge y>0\wedge z<x^2+y^2<1\}$$ and I want to evaluate the integral
$$\iiint_D\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2} }\, dx\, dy\, dz\,.$$

By using the cylindrical coordinates I obtain $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{r\cos \theta}^{r} \frac{r \sin \theta}{z^2+r^2}\, dz\, dr\, d\theta$$
Is it correct?

If I calculate it I found $\frac{\pi}{4}-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ and this integral exists finitely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the integral in cylindrical coordinates is written correctly. Your computation is almost right, but something happened near the end.
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{r\cos \theta}^{r} \frac{r \sin \theta}{z^2+r^2} dz\, dr\, d\theta&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{1} \sin \theta\left[\arctan(z/r)\right]_{r\cos \theta}^{r} dr\, d\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{1} \sin \theta\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan(\cos(\theta))\right) dr\, d\theta\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \arctan(\cos(\theta))(-\sin(\theta))d\theta\\&=
\frac{\pi}{4}-\int_{0}^{1} \arctan(t)dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\left[t\arctan(t)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)\right]_{0}^{1}=\frac{\ln(2)}{2}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is there $r^2$ in the integral?

Comment: No, see the first line.

Comment: ok.So near zero $\arctan t \sim t$ and the integral exists

Comment: Yes, and the remaining integral can be evaluated by parts.